# The counter number does not change (React JS)

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple counter on my web application.

When you press the button, the number should be incremented. But for some reason this doesn't happen.

So here's a code of an HTML element with a number:

```
<Text>{number}</Text>
```

And here's a counter button's onClick function:

```
<button onClick={(()=>number++)}>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple app which increases the number as you intend to:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=> setCounter(counter+1)}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-vaughan-s9h6g?file=/src/App.js:0-288)